# Should jQuery be injected

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, javascript

Is jQuery injection needed in following example ?

```
define(['jquery', 'componentX'], function(jQuery){ 
    jQuery('#test').html('')
})
```

What is worth to mention, **componentX** looks more or less like this:

```
define(['jquery'], function(jQuery){ 
   ...
})
```

Answer (score 0):

the question is not clear if you need only jquery

```
require(['jquery'], function ($) {
        $('#test').html('');
      });
```

and if you need to call another component

```
require(['jquery', 'componentX'], function ($, component) {
        $('#test').html(component());
      });
```

Comment: What's not clear for you? I can try to give more info about it, but the problem is simple. Well I asked this question cus first of all jQuery is available as a global object, so tehcnically if you don't inject the jQuery it will still work (at least if you use jQuery word) on the other side, considering that dependency injection is available I belive that jQuery should still be injected. I would like to ensure myslef in that statement, like mb someday jquery won't be avialable as a global object(thou this can never happen)